# How to match a n digit string where a particular digit if repeated and if together can only repeat m times?

Tags: python, regex

I have a 10 digit string and the condition is any number if repeated consecutively and can only be repeated 4 times, otherwise there is no limitation on repetitions

Example :

```
1234567890 "match"
1213141516 "match"
1111234567 "match"
1233333456 "not match"
```

How can I do it with regex?

Comment: Explain again why the third line is a match (4 ones) and the fourth is not (4 threes)?

Comment: That is five 3's, which is more than 4 so it should not match

Comment: Ah, right. Counted it wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regular expression, and return `'match'` or `'not_match'` depending on whether the capturing group was found or not.

`\1` will be specifying that you want `{4}` repetitions of the first capturing group:

```
def valid_string(s, lim=10):
    m = re.search(r'(\d)\1{4}', s)
    return 'match' if not m and len(s)==lim else 'not_match'
```

---

```
valid_string('1234567890')
# 'match'

valid_string('1111234567')
# 'match'

valid_string('1233333456')
# 'not_match'
```

Comment: The solution doesn't contain the constraint of 10 digits.

Comment: Is that a constraint too? Will update the answer. Note however that `"I have a 10 digit string"` doesn't seem like a constraint to me

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need to do this with RegEx rather than a simple loop containing:

```
/* Code to get current and previous char */
if (currentChar == previousChar) { numRepeats += 1; } else { numRepeats = 0; }
if (numRepeats > 4) { return false }
```

Comment: Lately, I am learning regex and trying out various problems like this. I agree, it can be easily done with loops and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?!\d*(\d)\1{4})\d{10}$`

As seen here https://regex101.com/r/LX8zQs/1